# How to send php variable to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to retrieve session variable data inside an ajax call. Here is my try.

```
$('#update').click(function(){  
            
           
           var number = $('#num').val();
           var curuser = <?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>
                

                if( number != '' && number.length==9 )
                {
                    
                     $.ajax({
                          data:{number:number},
                          success:function(data){ 
                   
                            $('#number_add').val(number); 
                            $('#new_data_Modal').modal('show'); 
                       }   
                          
                     });



                }
                
                   
      });
```

Seems like `var curuser = <?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>` prevents opening my model(new_data_Modal) after button(update) click. When I remove that line it works fine(Model is opening as previous).

But `alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>")` is working and it prints the session variable as well.

Can someone show me where I made the wrong?

Comment: wrap `<?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>` with quotes, because in your example in result you would have sth like following: `var curuser = userNameValue` which is not valid code in JS (if it would return string value). Also one suggestion (not really important) consider using `let` (mutable) and `const` (immutable) instead `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a string you need to wrap the variable in quotes:

```js
var curuser = '<?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>';
```

otherwise, when PHP code is executed you will get a syntax error:

```js
var curuser = John
```

You can check the source code of the generate HTML to see what is the output.

**NOTE**: Your javascript code needs to be a PHP file with a PHP extension, it can be your HTML or JavaScript file. You can use JS file as PHP script in script tag `<script src="code.php"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

If you're outputting JavaScript values from your php script you should use json_encode, that way any data type will work and there  is no risk of  your code breaking if you data has a quote or new line in it.

```
var curuser = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['userName']);?>
```